# NGRX : createReducer is hitting even the action is not called

Tags: angular, ngrx

My reducer function is in a feature module. When I try to lazy load another module as a child to this feature module, the reducer function gets triggered.

export const sessionReducer = createReducer(
initialSessionState,
on(SessionActions.loadSessionDetails, (state, request) => {
debugger;
return ({
...state,
loading: true,
error: '',
request: request
})
}),
);

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because the action `SessionActions.loadSessionDetails` is dispatched somewhere in the application.
An action is send to all reducers, so if that feature module is loaded, it receives actions from other features.